# jq convert jsonlines to csv with header without slurp

Tags: json, csv, optimization, jq, export-to-csv

a potentially huge json-lines file with objects of known structure is to be converted to csv with headers.

example

```
{"name":"name_0","value_a":"value_a_0","value_b":"val_b_0"}
{"name":"name_1","value_a":"value_a_1","value_b":"val_b_1"}
{"name":"name_2","value_a":"value_a_2","value_b":"val_b_2"}
{"name":"name_3","value_a":"value_a_3","value_b":"val_b_3"}
{"name":"name_4","value_a":"value_a_4","value_b":"val_b_4"}
```

expected output

```
"name","value_a","value_b"
"name_0","value_a_0","val_b_0"
"name_1","value_a_1","val_b_1"
"name_2","value_a_2","val_b_2"
"name_3","value_a_3","val_b_3"
"name_4","value_a_4","val_b_4"
```

currently tried

```
(if (input_line_number == 1 ) then ([.|to_entries|.[].key]|@csv) else empty end), 
(.|to_entries|[.[].value]|@csv  )
```

However this relies on the order in the json
as an alternative I have substituted it with directly selecting the values in the order I want.

```
(if (input_line_number == 1 ) then ("\"name\",\"value_a\",\"value_b\"") else empty end), (.|[.name?,.value_a?,.value_b?]|@csv  )
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/N5rdE9cOu-g)

any better solution? especially regarding the if, as it feels bulky.

I mainly don't want to use slurp because it will resort to load the whole file into memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overthink it; add a fixed header and use `inputs` together with `-n`/`--null-input` to format the actual content:

```
jq -n '["name", "value_a", "value_b"],
(inputs | [.name?, .value_a?, .value_b?])
| @csv' input.json
```

Output:

```
"name","value_a","value_b"
"name_0","value_a_0","val_b_0"
"name_1","value_a_1","val_b_1"
"name_2","value_a_2","val_b_2"
"name_3","value_a_3","val_b_3"
"name_4","value_a_4","val_b_4"
```

Comment: i dont get your output here https://jqplay.org/s/C1SjrzEhZaI it misses the first line

Comment: ok i get it the `-n` is important somehow. can you please add an explanation to your Answer? especially why it says in the docs that it wont read any input, but it obviously does?

Comment: @Summer-Sky `jq` by defaults reads input from stdin. With `-n`, it doesn't read any input, unless you explicitly read the remaining with the `inputs` filter. On jqplay, you have to enable "Null Input", otherwise the first input object in the stream will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

it's not jq, but I add it because I think it's interesting to know it.

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) and run

```
mlr --j2c cat input.jsonl >output.csv
```

you get

```
name,value_a,value_b
name_0,value_a_0,val_b_0
name_1,value_a_1,val_b_1
name_2,value_a_2,val_b_2
name_3,value_a_3,val_b_3
name_4,value_a_4,val_b_4
```